# row.tool_name is undefined in csv and js

Tags: javascript, csv

The logic behind the script is that, I have the CSV file to scrape the website using URL and saving the scraped data in JSON file. The problem here is that the function returns the url from the csv but not the name (const name = row.name is undefined) even with the same name in the csv as well as in the function it shows me error.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');

// Read the CSV file path from the command-line arguments
const csvFilePath = process.argv[2];

if (!csvFilePath) {
  console.error("CSV file path not provided.");
  process.exit(1);
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const scrapedData = [];

  // Read URLs from CSV file
  const dataFromCSV = [];
  fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {
      // Log the row to inspect column name
      console.log("CSV Row:", row);

      // Check for 'URL' or 'url' column
      const url = row.tool_url;
      const name = row.name;
      console.log("tool name", name)

      if (url) {
        dataFromCSV.push({ url, name });
      }
    })
    .on('end', async () => {
      // Log the extracted data to inspect
      console.log("Data from CSV:", dataFromCSV);

      // Iterate over each URL
      for (const item of dataFromCSV) {
        try {
          const data = await scrapeUrl(page, item.url);
          scrapedData.push({ tool_url: item.url, user_input: data });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error scraping URL: ${item.url}`);
          console.error(error);
        }
      }

      // Close the browser
      await browser.close();

      // Write the scraped data to a file
      fs.writeFileSync('scraped_output.json', JSON.stringify(scrapedData, null, 2));
      console.log(`Scraped data written to 'scraped_output.json'`);

      // Optional: Log the scraped data for debugging
      console.log('Scraped Data:', scrapedData);
    });
})();

async function scrapeUrl(page, url) {
  try {
    // Navigate to the URL
    await page.goto(url);

    // Wait for 5 seconds (adjust as needed)
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

    // Get the page content
    const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerText);

    return text;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error scraping URL: ${url}`);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error for better error handling in the calling function
  }
}
```

How to solve this?